# Concrete 5 using Page Types and Page Templates from main Theme

Tags: concrete5

it´s my first day with concrete5, i built a Sitemap with my Pages and added designs and Types. But the only used template is my default template, and i don´t know how to change it, cause i added page types and page templates as well.

help would be nice ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you start editing the template, make sure that you clear the cache [System & Setting -> Clear Cache]. As it will keep showing default.php until you do this. Are you using a custom template design? This may help: http://danmorgan.me/blog/concrete5-and-custom-themes/